# Aggregating a sub query within query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am currently working on aggregating the sum qty of "OUT" and "OUT+IN". 
Current query is the following:

```
Select 
a.Date
,a.DepartmentID

from 
(Select
dris.Date
,dris.RentalItemKey 
,dris.WarehouseKey
,ISNULL((Select TOP 1 dris.Date where OutQty=1 order by Date DESC),(Select ri.ReceiveDate from RentalItem ri where ri.RentalItemKey=dris.RentalItemKey)) as LastOutDate
,(Select d.DepartmentKey from Department d where d.Department=i.Department)as DepartmentID
, (CASE WHEN OutQty=1 OR (RepairQty=1 AND RentedQty=1) THEN 'IN' ELSE 'OUT' END) as Status

from DailyRentalItemStatus dris 
inner join Inventory i on i.InventoryKey=dris.InventoryKey
where dris.Date='2014-08-02'
and i.ICode='3223700'
and i.Classification IN ('ITEM', 'ACCESSORY')
and i.AvailFor='RENT'
and i.AvailFrom='WAREHOUSE'
and dris.Warehouse='TORONTO')a
```

and I would like the result to be the following:

```
Date       WarehouseID  DepartmentID    ICode   Owned   NotRedundant    Out
2014-08-02    001T         A00G        3223700   30         30          19
```

Where Owned is is The items with status as "OUT+IN", out is "OUT" and Not Redundant as where the lastout date is within the last 2 years from the date.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any `SUM()`, is part of your query missing?

Comment: You lost me on that last paragraph of explanation

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is close to what you're looking for. Your Not Redundant description, is hard to understand. Which dates are you comparing. The same trick for OUT may be used for that though. 
My query also assumes that you always have a department connecting to the inventory table and that there's always a rentalitem.receivedate.

```
;WITH LastOut as 
(Select Max(Date) as LastOutDate, rentalItemKey
from DailyRentalItemStatus
WHERE OutQty=1
)
Select
dris.Date
,dris.WarehouseKey as WarehouseID 
,d.DepartmentKey as DepartmentID
, i.Icode
--,ISNULL((Select TOP 1 dris.Date where OutQty=1 order by Date DESC),(Select ri.ReceiveDate from RentalItem ri where ri.RentalItemKey=dris.RentalItemKey)) as LastOutDate
, Count(1) as Owned
, Sum(CASE WHEN NOT (OutQty=1 OR (RepairQty=1 AND RentedQty=1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OUT
, Sum(CASE WHEN DateAdd(yy, 2,dris.[date]) >= ISNULL(lastout.lastoutdate, ri.ReceiveDate) then 1 else 0 end) as NonRedundent
from DailyRentalItemStatus dris 
inner join Inventory i on i.InventoryKey=dris.InventoryKey 
INNER JOIN Department d ON d.Department=i.Department
INNER JOIN RentalItem ri ON ri.RentalItemKey=dris.RentalItemKey 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LastOUT ON LastOut.rentalItemKey=dris.RentalItemKey
where dris.Date='2014-08-02'
and i.ICode='3223700'
and i.Classification IN ('ITEM', 'ACCESSORY')
and i.AvailFor='RENT'
and i.AvailFrom='WAREHOUSE'
and dris.Warehouse='TORONTO'
Group BY dris.Date, d.DepartmentKey, Dris.WarehouseKey , i.icode
```

Comment: Thanks this helps and is correct. However, I need to add the column NotRedundant, which basically takes the last out date (date when the item was last out order) but I don't want to add the outqty to the grouping column since I cannot add the sum without adding it to the group clause.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I think what you're saying is that you need to compare the lastOutDate with every dris.Date to determine which to add to the nonrendundant column. If so, I think the above will work.